# Writing common file with replacements in bash

Tags: bash, ubuntu, file-io, filesystems

I am writing a script to setup new projects on my computer,

One part I am wanting to do is have it automatically setup the virtual hosts for me.

The file itself is quite simple

the file should be called `<project>.testfox.dev.conf` and should contain

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "/var/www/work/<project>"
ServerName <project>.testfox.dev
<Directory "/var/www/work/<project>">
allow from all
Options +Indexes
</Directory>
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/<project>.error.log
LogLevel error
TransferLog /var/log/apache2/<project>.access.log
</VirtualHost>
```

What I wonder is, should I have that code in my script and write it out line by line to the file, or should I have a dummy file in the sites-available folder that I copy and then search a replace a placeholder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most flexible way would be to have it as a template (either as a separate file, or a HEREDOC), writing it line-by-line would make it very hard to modify in future.

The HEREDOC approach would be easier to implement, as you can use variable interpolation:

```
cat >$PROJECT.testfox.dev.conf <<EOF

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "/var/www/work/$PROJECT"
ServerName $PROJECT.testfox.dev
<Directory "/var/www/work/$PROJECT">
allow from all
Options +Indexes
</Directory>
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/$PROJECT.error.log
LogLevel error
TransferLog /var/log/apache2/$PROJECT.access.log
</VirtualHost>
EOF
```

Comment: Ahh now this looks interesting, the only issue is I cannot work out how to make it write to the file using sudo (the script itself is not run using sudo)

Comment: @Hailwood You can create the conf file and then `sudo cp /tmp/project.conf /etc/apache/sites-enabled/`.

Comment: @OlafDietsche That's what I was thinking of doing, I was just wondering if there was a way to do it with piping

Comment: my suggestion would be to avoid sudo for this, and give the appropriate permissions to the target directory (group writable, and the user in the appropriate group)

Answer (score 1):

Both are viable approaches.

Using it as a template makes it easier and more readable, if you want to modify it. But keeping it in a bash script as a [here document](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Documents) works as well.

In the end, it depends on what your preferences are.

Comment: Any chance of you providing a simple example of the here document replacement?

Comment: @Hailwood Please look at Sorin's answer, I could only duplicate his excellent script.